# Filter already filtered mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I am building a REST Api for an HR service and need to implement filters working with Flask and Pymongo. I have a few filters such as technology, experience, city, framework etc. What I am trying to do is to filter by technology first and if some conditions are met further in the process, to filter its query by another condition. It is sort of like a Django queryset that you can narrow down further.

But I can't find it on Mongo docs if I can do sort of:

```
collection = db.my_collection.find({technologies: 'Python'})
narrowed_collection = collection.filter({framework: 'Flask'})
```

I know I can run the second query in one place but in my case I find it more efficient to do it if some conditions are met. At least, I would certainly do it this way in Django.

Is there any solution?

EDIT:

Here is a copy of a document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d965a8b7ae4614204182cc2"),
    "Name" : "John Doe",
    "Rating" : "9870.31",
    "Technologies" : [ 
        "Java", 
        "HTML", 
        "Python", 
        "PHP", 
        "JavaScript", 
        "CSS"
    ],
    "About" : "Flask, Django, React, Angular",
    "Location": "London, UK",
    "Experience"
}
```

Say I am filtering by Technology, Experience and Location. But I am also looking for a Flask framework and it is "nice to have" a React. It means that not only do we need those who have both of them (Flask and React) but first we need those who have 2 of them and then those who have only Flask.

Say we filtered by the first 3 fields and got 5k items out of a 100k collection. Next, to achieve this 2 frameworks search I am running a complex aggregation, so I feel like it is much better for a performance to run aggregation on 5k results then on 100k.

Comment: can you provide sample documents and desired output ?

Comment: Hi there, I have edited the initial question under EDIT section. Thanks!